# How do I move an object that was already placed in Fortnite Creative 1.0?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

In Fortnite Creative on Xbox, I’m trying to move vending machines that I have names on, but if I try copy and pasting, it adds on a number. Also the same with bigger objects.
So how do I move objects that I had already placed without having to copy and past everything?